# c# windows forms app /client server /checking client input to do something is not working in

Tags: c#, multithreading, multiple-conditions

I'm creating a **client server app** using **c#** and what it does :

1- the **client sends a msg** then the **server sends it back** to the **client**

2- I want to **check** what the client send and do some process like if the **client send** **"chrome"**
the **server checks it** and open **chrome.exe**

I don't know why its not working here on my code:

when the client sends **chrome** it always shows **client disconnected message**
also i cant convert it to windows froms app its shows lots of errors

**#server code!**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace consoleTcpServer {

    class Program {
        class ConnectionHandler {
            private Socket client;
            private NetworkStream ns;
            private StreamReader reader;
            private StreamWriter writer;
            private static int connections = 0;

            //The constructor take the accepted client as argument
            public ConnectionHandler(Socket client) {
                this.client = client;
            }

            public void HandleConnection() {

                try {
                    ns = new NetworkStream(client);
                    reader = new StreamReader(ns);
                    writer = new StreamWriter(ns);
                    connections++;
                    Console.WriteLine("New client accepted: {0} active   connections",
                        connections);
                    writer.WriteLine("Welcome to my server");
                    writer.Flush();
                    string input;
                    while ((input = reader.ReadLine()).Length != 0) {

                        if (input.Contains("chrome")) {
                            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "www.google.com");
                        } else if (input.Contains("fox")) {
                            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", "www.facebook.com");
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(input);
                        writer.WriteLine(input);
                        writer.Flush();
                    }

                    // ns.Close();
                    // client.Close();
                    connections--;
                    Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected: {0} active connections", connections);
                } catch (Exception) {
                    connections--;
                    Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected: {0} active   connections",
                        connections);

                }

            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
            server.Bind(localEP);
            server.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client");

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket client = server.Accept();
                    ConnectionHandler handler = new ConnectionHandler(client);
                    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(handler.HandleConnection));
                    thread.Start();

                } catch (Exception) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection failed ..");
                }
                //client.Close();
                //server.Shutdown();

            }

        }

    }
}
```

**#client code**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

namespace consoleTcpClient {
    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            //  Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);

            client.Connect(remoteEP);

            NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            String input = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            String line = null;

            while (true) {
                Console.Write("Enter Message for Server <Enter to  Stop >: ");
                line = Console.ReadLine();

                //writing for server
                writer.WriteLine(line);
                writer.Flush();

                if (line.Length != 0) {
                    line = "Echo: " + reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            // client.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried debugging your code? I would recommend debugging and especially looking at your server side loop and whats reaches the input variable.

Comment: im sorry idk how to do this can you show me exactly

Comment: No. But i can tell you what you should read. Debugging is no magic but can't be described in some short sentences https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Comment: i did it  ! the input variable holds the value chrome and its true but after that it goes to catch Exception part and does not exeute the process open chrome.exe .. im srry but i have this project for school it due tomorrow :(

Comment: You should evaluate the exception and look what it tells you. Presumably it just can't find the chrome executable.

Comment: it worked for me when i was using a simple not threaded tcp Listener class but now im using sockets and threads ..

Comment: Client never sends anything so nothing happens.  Client has to send one message before loop so code works.

Comment: when i type anything other than "chrome" or "fox" its sends and receives normally

Comment: IT WORKD @Ralf i deleted the exception that it was on the catch part and i saw the real error it was denied by windows i had to change environment var